# JSF Navigation Rules with Relative Paths

Tags: java, url, jsf, navigation

Say I am on a page at

```
www.foo.com/foo/bar/page.jsf
```

and want to define a navigation rule to go to

```
www.foo.com/foo/
```

how would I define the `<to-view-id>`  of the navigation rule. I thought it would be something like this:

```
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>goToFoo</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/../</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

but that throws a parser error when called. I figure I am missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF navigation rules are relative to the application context, not relative to the current page. If `foo` is your app context, then `/page.jsp` will always go to `www.foo.com/foo/page.jsf`, not `www.foo.com/foo/bar/page.jsf`.

Also, I believe you must refer to actual pages e.g. you must include the `page.jsf` portion.