# Page redirect not working in JSF

Tags: html, jsf

My directory structure is like this.

```
-- dir
   -- dir1
      --file_1
   -- dir2
      --file_2
```

I have one jsf button as mentioned below.

```
<h:commandButton id="Register" style="background:#50A7E6;color:white" value="Register" action="../dir1/file_1?faces-redirect=true" class="btn btn-info loginmodal-submit"></h:commandButton>
```

I want to redirect from file_2 to file_1. As I mentioned in the action part, It should work but It is not redirecting to the page.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869774/jsf-navigation-rules-with-relative-paths) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683584/what-url-to-use-to-link-navigate-to-other-jsf-pages), you **cannot** use JSF navigation on such way because JSF navigation is not relative to current directory but to application context.

And, in your case, `p:commandButton` is appending application context path to `action` parameter path and that is why it cannot work as you expect.

As far as I know, you **can** use, for example

```
 <h:outputLink value="../dir1/page1.xhtml">Go to DIR 1 Page 1</h:outputLink>
```

to browse relatively to directories (in your example, from /dir2/page2 to dir1/page1)